# Get rid of some dangling print jobs in my printer's queue

Tags: windows-10, printer, network-printer, print-spooler

It is over a week now that I cannot get rid of a two print jobs dangling in my printer's queue:

[image]

[image]

Things tried so far:

- using *Restart* or *Cancel* on each of these two tasks in printer queue,
- using *Printer > Cancel all documents* in printer queue,
- restarting PC and Windows (many times),
- using Windows Troubleshooter to fix printer problem (did not find any problems with the printer),
- [resetting printer's spooler](https://support.4it.com.au/article/restart-printer-spooler-windows-10/).

No effect, print jobs are still there. Anything else that I can try?

Answer (score 1):

Turned out that I have made things in an incorrect order. The [correct order](http://onezeronull.com/2020/06/02/correct-steps-order-for-getting-rid-of-unfinished-print-jobs/) is:

- [reset printer's spooler](https://support.4it.com.au/article/restart-printer-spooler-windows-10/) **and** (after that),
- use *Printer > Cancel all documents* in printer queue.

This finally purged my printer's queue out of all dangling and unfinished print jobs.